# What's the logical execution order of this Python decorated function?

Tags: python, decorator

Imagine this:

```
def b1(fnc):
  print "b1"
  return fnc

@b1
def a1():
  print "a1"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  a1() # will print b1 a1
```

So, when I'm using `@b1`, a1 gets turned to `a1 = b1(a1)`, right?
Then, when I say:

```
a1()
```

This turns to:

```
b1(a1)
```

And then goes into:

```
print "b1"
return fnc
```

Where/Who exactly is calling fnc? I have a feeling I'm asking a very stupid question, but I want to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The decorator is only executed once. It takes a callable object and returns a callable object.** The object that it returns is used in place of `a1`.

In other words, `b1` is called at the point where `a1` is defined. It prints out `"b1"` and returns `a1` unchanged. Since it returns `a1` unchanged, `b1` plays no role whatsoever in any subsequent calls to `a1`.

Therefore, the following comment isn't quite correct:

```
  a1() # will print b1 a1
```

In fact,

- `a1()` only prints `"a1"`.
- The `"b1"` that you see is printed by `@b1` / `def a1():`.

If you change the code like so and re-run, the sequence of events should become clearer:

```
def b1(fnc):
  print "b1"
  return fnc

@b1
def a1():
  print "a1"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print 'in __main__'
  a1()
  a1()
```

Finally, to achieve the effect you were looking for, the decorator would need to return a different callable object:

```
def b1(fnc):
  def decorated():
    print "b1"
    return fnc()
  return decorated

@b1
def a1():
  print "a1"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print 'in __main__'
  a1()
  a1()
```

Here, it is pretty clear who is calling `fnc()`.

Comment: The key idea is that a function definition is just another peace of code that gets executed (usually only once). The decorator is only execute when the function definition is executed.

Answer (score 1):

> Who is calling `fnc`?

Basically, the `()` behind `a1` in the last line of the code.

So what is going on? Decorators are meant to change the behavior of functions.

So when you decorate something, a new function is created based on what the decorator returns. This means the decorator runs once *when `a1` is defined*. Here is an example that demonstrates this:

```
print 'def b1'
def b1(fnc):
  print "b1"
  return fnc

print 'def a1'
@b1
def a1():
  print "a1"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print 'main'
  a1() # will print b1 a1
```

This will print:

```
def b1
def a1
b1
main
a1
```

As you can see, the decorator `b1` is called before `main` is executed.

It returns a function instance which is assigned to the alias `a1` which can be used like any other function instance.

This what the "call operator" `()` after the `a1` in the last line of the code does.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the top answer of [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators)

In that you'll notice that the decorator definition is actually transforming the function, and returning the transformed function. That is executed once upon decoration (when the @... is applied). In the example you give, b1 is not defining a transformation but the print statement still gets executed. The original function is then returned, therefore a1 does not get "redefined". the action of the b1 decorator then is to do nothing to a1.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call `a1_prev`, the `a1` function before being decorated, `a1()` turns into

```
b1(a1_prev)()
```

and not only `b1(a1_prev)`, the last `()` are those who call the `func` returned by `b1`.